# excel chart based on switch

Tags: excel, charts, legend, dashboard

I'd like to create an excel dashboard where the user selects which series are plotted based on a drop down menu. The series for the chart is derived as follows:

```
=IF(J$6="Plot",100 * D8/D$108,"")
```

etc.

If I turn off "Plot" the series disappears form the chart but an empty line persists in the legend. I'd like the legend to include only the series I have selected. 
[image]

Thank you in advance,

Tikhon

Comment: Formulas can't be used to control which series are included in a chart or in the legend of a chart. You need to use either a pivotchart where users can select field items, or VBA (which would run better on buttons/checkboxes than cell values)

Comment: Create the formulae so that they use the relevant selected data which is then used by the chart series.

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate?